# PHP Preg_match Image from url

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, preg-match

I am trying to parse a website and grab the name or url of the image.

Example URL:
http://www.theworkingmanstore.com/georgia-gr14-infants-romeo.aspx

There are 6 images or more in a single `<td>` and I only want to get the first img src in that `<td>`.

I am sure it can probably be done with Dom Parser, but I have no experience with it.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$reg = '/img src=["\']?([^"\' ]*)["\' ]/';
preg_match_all($reg, $html, $m);
$arr = array_map(function($v){
return trim(str_replace(array('img src=', 'http://www.theworkingmanstore.com'), '', $v), '"');}, $m[0]);
print_r($arr)
```

Output:
This is output from regex

```
Array
(
    [0] => /images/logo2.png
    [1] => /images/mod_head_category_lt.gif
    [2] => '/images/products/display/GR14_EXTRALARGE.jpg'
    [3] => '/images/products/thumb/GR14_EXTRALARGE.jpg'
    [4] => '/images/products/thumb/GR14_8_EXTRALARGE.jpg'
    [5] => '/images/products/thumb/GR14_5_EXTRALARGE.jpg'
    [6] => '/images/products/thumb/GR14_3_EXTRALARGE.jpg'
    [7] => '/images/products/thumb/GR14_42_EXTRALARGE.jpg'
    [8] => '/images/products/thumb/GR14_2_EXTRALARGE.jpg'
    [9] => /images/freeshipping.jpg
    [10] => /images/facebook_32.png
    [11] => images/twitter_32.png
    [12] => images/googleplus_32.png
    [13] => images/pinterest_32.png
    [14] => /images/payments.gif
    [15] => /images/brands/the-working-man.jpg
)
```

Tried the Dom Parser suggestion:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url) ;
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->evaluate(
'string(//td/a[@id = "Zoomer"]/descendant::img[1]/@src)'
);
```

Got Error as output:
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Tag nav invalid in Entity

Comment: You say you have no experience with the DOM parser, but this might well be the perfect time to learn how to use it. Chances are you're going to run into the shortcomings of using regexes to parse HTML again in the future, perhaps even on this very project.  Regexes are just not up to the task of parsing arbitrary HTML.

Answer (score 4):

In DOM anything is a node, the `img` elements and the `src` attributes, too. XPath allows you to fetch nodes lists from a DOM.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//img/@src') as $src) {
  echo $src->value, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
http://www.theworkingmanstore.com/images/products/display/GR14_EXTRALARGE.jpg
http://www.theworkingmanstore.com/images/products/detail/GR14_EXTRALARGE.jpg
/images/products/thumb/GR14_EXTRALARGE.jpg
/images/products/thumb/GR14_8_EXTRALARGE.jpg
/images/products/thumb/GR14_5_EXTRALARGE.jpg
/images/products/thumb/GR14_3_EXTRALARGE.jpg
/images/products/thumb/GR14_42_EXTRALARGE.jpg
/images/products/thumb/GR14_2_EXTRALARGE.jpg
```

XPath allows quit complex conditions. The following examples outputs the `src` attributes of the first `img` inside any `td`.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//td/descendant::img[1]/@src') as $src) {
  echo $src->value, "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
http://www.theworkingmanstore.com/images/products/display/GR14_EXTRALARGE.jpg
```

The HTML in the question contains only a single `td`, and more important the `img` is inside an `a` element with an `id` attribute. So it has to be a single unique value. This allows it to cast the node list directly in XPath and return it as a string.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->evaluate(
  'string(//td/a[@id = "Zoomer"]/descendant::img[1]/@src)'
);
```

Output:

```
http://www.theworkingmanstore.com/images/products/display/GR14_EXTRALARGE.jpg
```

Comment: I attempted this, and got this error
: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [<a href='domdocument.loadhtml'>domdocument.loadhtml</a>]: Tag nav invalid in Entity. using $html = file_get_contents($url) before the first line of code to speciy the the html to parse

Comment: This are warning because the HTML is not fully valid HTML 4 (`nav` is a HTML5 tag), you can silence them with `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`.

Comment: Updated initial question with both suggestions.

Comment: Adding the libxml_clear_errors();   resolved it. Appreciate everyones help

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this regex.

```
$html = 'Your HTML';
$reg = '/img src=["\']?([^"\' ]*)["\' ]/';
preg_match_all($reg, $html, $m);
$arr = array_map(function($v){
    return trim(str_replace(array('img src=', 'http://www.theworkingmanstore.com'), '', $v), '"');
}, $m[0]);

print '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => /images/products/display/GR14_EXTRALARGE.jpg
    [1] => /images/products/detail/GR14_EXTRALARGE.jpg
    [2] => /images/products/thumb/GR14_EXTRALARGE.jpg
    [3] => /images/products/thumb/GR14_8_EXTRALARGE.jpg
    [4] => /images/products/thumb/GR14_5_EXTRALARGE.jpg
    [5] => /images/products/thumb/GR14_3_EXTRALARGE.jpg
    [6] => /images/products/thumb/GR14_42_EXTRALARGE.jpg
    [7] => /images/products/thumb/GR14_2_EXTRALARGE.jpg
)
```

Comment: Actually it parses the image i need to this:
'/images/products/display/GR14_EXTRALARGE.jpg'
dont want the single quotes around it

Comment: Updated answer, try now!

Comment: Still didnt work.I updated the array output to my initial question from your example. Some have single quotes around and others do not. Guess would need some preg_replace ?